# Tomcat startup issue(web.xml)

Tags: spring, tomcat

I'm trying to run a spring mvc basic app with tomcat and getting http 404 error. I get the below start up error. This was working before and i have no clue what went wrong with we.xml

```
May 21, 2013 6:09:37 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property       'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:testspring' did not find a matching property.
May 21, 2013 6:09:37 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
May 21, 2013 6:09:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 471 ms
May 21, 2013 6:09:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
May 21, 2013 6:09:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.33
May 21, 2013 6:09:37 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
SEVERE: End event threw exception
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at        org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.callMethodN(IntrospectionUtils.java:959)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.CallMethodMultiRule.end(WebRuleSet.java:789)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Rule.end(Rule.java:229)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1138)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1642)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationWebConfig(ContextConfig.java:365)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.start(ContextConfig.java:1076)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:261)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4612)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown   servlet name frontcontrol
at  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:2739)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:2719)
... 37 more
May 21, 2013 6:09:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig applicationWebConfig
SEVERE: Parse error in application web.xml file at jndi:/localhost/testspring/WEB-   INF/web.xml
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name   frontcontrol
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2806)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2832)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1141)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
at  com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1642)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationWebConfig(ContextConfig.java:365)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.start(ContextConfig.java:1076)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:261)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4612)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown  servlet name frontcontrol
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:2739)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:2719)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at     org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.callMethodN(IntrospectionUtils.java:959)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.CallMethodMultiRule.end(WebRuleSet.java:789)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Rule.end(Rule.java:229)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1138)
... 29 more
May 21, 2013 6:09:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig applicationWebConfig
SEVERE: Occurred at line 20 column 21
May 21, 2013 6:09:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig start
SEVERE: Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s)
May 21, 2013 6:09:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
May 21, 2013 6:09:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/testspring] startup failed due to previous errors
May 21, 2013 6:09:38 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
May 21, 2013 6:09:38 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
May 21, 2013 6:09:38 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/26  config=null
May 21, 2013 6:09:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 309 ms
```

I don't see anything wrong with my web.xml. Can someone help me to sort this out?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>testspring</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>frontcontrol</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/611465/tomcat-is-unable-to-find-my-servlet-and-is-throwing-exceptions-but-why

Comment: Did you look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293797/tomcat-startup-web-xml-issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See this in stackTrace

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown   servlet name frontcontrol

you have servlet-mapping for frontControl .... but no corrosponding SERVLET tag...

I think This should be correct mapping in your case.

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>frontcontrol</servlet-name><!-- Notice this line changed-->
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>frontcontrol</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```