# servlet class not getting generated and version of JDK used to start tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, netbeans

My directory structure for a servlet in netbeans is as follows:

[image]

Q1. Is it mandatory that I should see servlet class below my `web.xml`. It's not getting generated for me. Because I believe I need to specify the class name in the `web.xml` inside the `<servlet`> tag.

Q2. How do I find out which JDK version is used to start the tomcat? I have JDK 1.8 installed on my machine and I am using that in NEtbeans 7.4. I am running into the same problem as asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611465/tomcat-is-unable-to-find-my-servlet-and-is-throwing-exceptions-but-why) and trying to find a fix based on the @Macon Pegram's answer mentioned over there.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q1:** Am not sure i got your question. But What i understand is , you are expecting a servlet class generated from your index.jsp and placed under WEB-INF right?

jsp files are converted to servlet in run time, you cannot see them in your project directory structure. But if you really want to see them `target\tomcat\work\localEngine\localhost\<name related to webapp>\org\apache\jsp` is the location of the generated servlets.

**Q2:**
You can see in server and settings tab while creating new app. or you can see in server properties.

Hope it helps